# Local incremental map of values with Kafka streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am looking at the [Pipe](https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/tutorial) streams tutorial. I need something similar, but only local.

In other words, the code in the example is:

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input").to("streams-pipe-output");

final Topology topology = builder.build();
final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
```

which would take messages from `streams-plaintext-input` topic and put them into `streams-pipe-output` topic.

Is there a way to do this without creating an output topic? In other words, have each client use streams and just get the output locally?

The use case is basically to get messages and perform some filtering, grouping and such and then to consume that stream as if it were the original stream.

However, there are going to be a lot of consumers with different transformation criteria and I'd not like to have a topic for each of them, especially since this is temporary data, more like a continuous cache.

If there are some tutorials or examples that I can go through, please let me know.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by _then to consume that stream as if it were the original stream_? If you need to transform data you just need to: builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input").filter(...).map(...) etc.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "locally" -- maybe `KStream#foreach()` is what you are looking for? -- Also, if you want to apply different processing, you can "reuse" the same `KStream stream` variable and "broadcast" the data into different pipeline: `stream.filter(); ... stream.map()` etc. Overall, you should read the docs and check out the examples (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html and https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples)